# How to manage Continuous Changing values in an array of strings

Tags: java, android

I have an array of strings but the values in array is changing continuously changing.
Is there any other way of managing the array except removing items and changing index locations?

```
public int[] deviceId=null;
deviceId=new String[deviceCount];
```

in my case deviceCount is changing as new device comes. so i continuously need to change array size and add or remove items

Comment: what do you mean "manage" ? what are you trying to use the strings for? The more information you can provide the more likely you are to get useful answers here.

Comment: I would say you are looking for `List` like `ArrayList` but you need to provide more details of what your code is doing and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Your question will be probably put on hold if you wont [[edit]] it and provide more details.

Comment: put your source code .

Comment: public int[] deviceId=null;
deviceId=new String[deviceCount];

In my case deviceCount is changing so i need to remove and add values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java offers a really handy mechanism known as the ArrayList. It's a dynamic array that you can use to do what you're describing.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: sure thing. click the green checkmark to mark this as the correct answer and welcome to Stack